# JavaFXML Assistance - Coin Counter

Tags: java

I have been learning Java for the past month and I have branched out more than what my class has learned and decided to start making a GUI program that has various conversion calculators.  However, there is one that is giving me trouble.  It seems so simple to me but for some reason it is not working.

What I want to do is make it where when I click the convert button, the program converts the dollar amount to quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies where pennies will be the lowest amount possible.  I am configuring this through a controller Class linked to my main Class.  I have attached my code below.  Thank you!

```
package calculator.coins;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CoinsController {

@FXML
private Button convertButton;

@FXML
private Button resetButton;

@FXML
private TextField dollarsText;

@FXML 
private TextField quartersText;

@FXML
private TextField dimesText;

@FXML
private TextField nickelsText;

@FXML
private TextField penniesText;

@FXML
private void ConvertDollars(ActionEvent event)
{
    double monetary_amount, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    monetary_amount = Double.parseDouble(dollarsText.getText().toString());

    quarters = (monetary_amount / .25);
    monetary_amount = monetary_amount%.25;

    dimes = (monetary_amount / .10);
    monetary_amount = monetary_amount%.10;

    nickels = (monetary_amount / .05);
    monetary_amount = monetary_amount%0.05;

    pennies = (monetary_amount / .01);
    monetary_amount = monetary_amount%.01;

    quartersText.setText("" +quarters);
    dimesText.setText("" +dimes);
    nickelsText.setText("" +nickels);
    penniesText.setText("" +pennies);
}

@FXML
private void resetProg(ActionEvent event)
{
    quartersText.setText("");
    dimesText.setText("");
    nickelsText.setText("");
    penniesText.setText("");
    dollarsText.requestFocus();
}
```

}

Comment: What exectly isn´t working? And what would you expect? Looking at your code I assume, that the "ConvertDollars" method (which you should name with a lowercase "c" by convention) is called and you see no result. That´s because you assign the result only to a local variable. You have to put the result of your calculation into a text field or something.

Comment: When I convert the dollars, the program sets the text of the quartersText to 0, dimesText to 1, nickelsText to 1, penniesText to 0.  Instead I want it to where when I click the button after I input my dollar amount, it will populated the various coin text fields with the most amount of coins possible where pennies would be what is left of all the others.  So essentially, quarters then dimes then nickels then pennies.  I can get the program to work in console but not in the GUI and they are set up exactly the same.

Comment: Do I get it right: You insert 1 dollar end get the output 0 quarters, 1 dimes, 1 nickels and 0 pennies?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Instead it should output what the correct change is.

Answer (score 0):

refer this code of controll

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package exercise14;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import
        javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 *
 * @author j
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController {
    public Label output;
 //   public int b;
      public int c;
    public Label  o2;
    public Label  o3;
    public Label  o4;
       public int e;
       
   public TextField input;
    public void maths(){
   String j= input.getText();
   int a =Integer.parseInt(j);
   
   if(a>=25){
       int b=a/25;
       
    output.setText(String.valueOf(b));}
   }
    if(a%25>=10)
    {    int c=a%25; //17
    int d=c/10; 
   
    o2.setText(String.valueOf(d));
    }
  //  o3.setText(String.valueOf());
    if((a%25)%10>=1){
    int e =(a%25)%10; //7
    int f=e/5;
     o3.setText(String.valueOf(f));
    }
    
    if((((a%25)%10)%5)>=1){
        int m=((a%25)%10)%5;
        o4.setText(String.valueOf(m));
    }
    }
       
    
}
```